# How to manage MS Excel application processes in MS Access VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have the below code that results in a rogue excel process which interferes with subsequent executions. I'm wondering what I am doing wrong that is leaving this open.

However, if i set xl.visible = true then the process is killed when the application closes.

I believe the issue to be centered around

```
Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Add(templatePath)
```

After the application runs, if I open one of the files created, it opens the template workbook as well. That seems to be the hanging process.

```
Public Function CreateAYRs()

'This process is known to leave a hanging excel process open after execution.

'database objects
Dim rsHeader As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsDetail As DAO.Recordset
Dim db As DAO.Database
'Excel objects
Dim xl As Excel.Application
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim templatewb As Workbook
'paths
Dim templatePath As String
Dim outboxPath As String

On Err GoTo ErrHandler

templatePath = "\\ahmtroy03\sppcsharedfiles\6290 Procurement Operations\Systems\Applications\AYR\AYR Form.xlsx"
outboxPath = "\\ahmtroy03\sppcsharedfiles\6290 Procurement Operations\_Public\Data\AYR\Sent\"

Set db = CurrentDb()

Set rsHeader = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM qryAYRtoSendHeader")

If Not rsHeader.BOF And Not rsHeader.EOF Then
    'there is a PO, create the parent application
    Set xl = New Excel.Application
    'xl.Visible = True

    rsHeader.MoveFirst
    While (Not rsHeader.EOF)
        'There will be a new workbook for each PO
        Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Add(templatePath)
        'Get all the lines
        Set rsDetail = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT [Due Date],[Model],[Part Number],[Part Desc] FROM qryAYRtoSendDetail WHERE [VC] In('" & rsHeader![VC] & "')")
        If Not rsDetail.BOF And Not rsDetail.EOF Then
            'Move the data to the spreadsheet
            wb.Sheets(2).Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rsDetail
        End If
        'cleanup
        rsDetail.Close
        Set rsDetail = Nothing

        'Save the form, supress overwrite warnings
        wb.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        wb.SaveAs outboxPath & "AHM AYR " & rsHeader![VC] & " - " & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yy"), FileFormat:=51
        wb.Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        'email the form

        wb.Close False
        Set wb = Nothing
        'move to the next PO
        rsHeader.MoveNext
    Wend
xl.Quit
Set xl = Nothing
End If
'cleanup
rsHeader.Close
Set rsHeader = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

Exit Function
ErrHandler:
MsgBox Err.Description

End Function
```

Comment: Do you have any error handling? It's possible that it throws an error before you clean up the `xl` object, which would keep the process running. Add in the handling and clean up the objects within that block as well and see if the process continues after execution.

Comment: Ran your code. I do NOT see residual Excel process. I did make it a Sub instead of Function but I doubt that made a difference

Comment: I have Windows Explorer preview pane active. If I view a workbook in Explorer, Excel process is created and it doesn't go away, even if I delete the workbook, until I close the Explorer window. However, this is not preventing running the procedure.

Comment: Why do you close and open the workbook in every iteration of the loop. Since you're apparently working with the same workbook all the time, why not close it after the loop? What's with the Excel variables (ws, templatesb) that you declar but don't use? Have you edited the code for posting here? If yes, is it possible the problem is in what you've edited out?

Comment: He is creating a new workbook for each row of `rsHeader` @CindyMeister. -- But the other question is relevant: does the code as posted in the question actually show the problematic behavior? Check the *Verifiable* part of [mcve].

Comment: @MoondogsMaDawg I have added error handling. Not exactly what you had in mind but hopefully I would get a message.

Comment: @CindyMeister I have removed unnecessary declarations. I apologize. I started out thinking I would use those and I never did. Oops!

Comment: @Andre I have removed unnecessary declarations.

Comment: @June7 That's interesting! I do not have the preview pane open but I'll definitely keep that in mind.

Comment: @June7 After all the changes suggested by everyone and also changing to a sub, still a hanging process. However, after adding error handling and suppressing save as errors, the hanging processes never cause subsequent execution errors. They just add up over time.

Comment: Are you using early or late binding?  You use `Dim xl As Object` and subsequent `CreateObject...` which is late binding, but then you also use `Dim wb As Workbook` which is early binding.  No idea if it will be part of the problems being experienced, but seems a little odd.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook I have honestly never looked in to the difference but I'm feeling like an early binding kind of guy. Code updated!

Comment: It might affect when Access releases the variables - I generally use late binding to make my code non-version specific.  While looking at the early binding it does seem that the process is removed and variables are released as soon as the code finishes.

Comment: *I believe the issue to be centered around `Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Add(templatePath)`* - have you tried what happens if you leave the `Template` parameter empty? Of course the files won't look as they should, just to see if it changes anything.

Comment: I never seen or used such a method: `Workbooks.Add(templatePath)`. I usually directly open the template file, add needed data and save as a new workbook.

Comment: @Parfait I tried changing this to Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(templatePath) and I'm getting the same behavior.

Comment: @Andre I tried not using a template and still get a process. I did notice that if I open an excel spreadsheet manually and close it, that removes the process.

Comment: Why are you also doing wb.Save? Isn’t the wb.SaveAs sufficient?

Comment: @RachelHettinger wb.Save was a way for me to see which workbook I was actually in and where. It saves it to My Documents as templatePath1, which I thought was interesting.

Comment: Yes, it’s exactly the same result as if you save a new file that was based on the default template, e.g. Book1.

Comment: Oh, I used a regular Excel workbook, extension xlsx so just created file with the xltm extension and modified code to use that file. No change. No residual process.

Comment: I can't reproduce either but you mentioned if you make the Excel application visible it does work. Could you just add `xl.Visible = true` immediately before `xl.Quit` as a workaround?

Comment: @andrew I actually thought the EXACT same thing and it didn't work !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a lot of very helpful and creative suggestions provided but the solution was actually way off-base.

I did some more research and found somewhere that suggested that the issue could be due to Excel COM addins. I disabled all of my add-ins (one of which is corporate issued) and the hanging excel process issue stopped completely.